# How to delete thousands of png files in a directory based on a string in the middle of the filename?

Tags: regex, terminal, grep

I have a directory with 150,000 png files. I need to delete about 70,000 of them.

The files I need to delete have a string "&zoom=9&" in the middle of the file name, like this:

```
Historical_Min_Temp_of_coldest_Month&zoom=9&x=129&y=377.png
```

I want to keep all the other files in the directory (with zoom levels 0-8). I'm on a Mac.

I have tried:

```
ls *zoom=9*
grep '^\./zoom-9'
find -P | grep 'zoom=9'
```

But I'm obviously missing some core concepts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not general tech support about using the computer.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and is better suited for unix.stackexchange.com (or a quick google search)

Answer (score 2):

If you have several subdirectories you can try this:

```
find . -name "*&zoom=9&*" -delete
```

or (less preferred)

```
find . -name "*&zoom=9&*" -exec rm {} +
```

The fist version removes the files internally, so no additional external executables are launched. Closing the line with `+` instead of the usual `\;` add as many found files as fits to the command line buffer, reducing the number of external calls (similar to the external `xargs` utility)

(I do not have Mac, this is the Linux version, but I assume that these features are basic ones and supported by OSX)

I would like to propose something. Do not store 100 000+ files in one directory. This can slow down your system and deleting files will not solve the problem. To reduce the size of a directory i-node, you have to (hard)link all files under a new directory and remove the old directory.

Comment: Good point about storing 100,000 files in one directory.  That system is fine if you don't think you'll go over 1000, otherwise they should be in their own directory.

Answer (score 1):

Is `rm *zoom=9*.png` not working?

Comment: If there are a lot of files this solution can cause a command line buffer overrun. To avoid this `xargs` or `find` should be used. To check the size of the command line buffer run `xargs --show-limits`.

Comment: It seems that my comment mentions just a possibility. I tested in  [tab:bash] under [tag:linux] and it did not have the affect I mentioned. I tested `echo $(find)|wc` and the output is `1   31463 2114170`, so the single command line is over 2MB! If I check the command line buffer max size with `getconf ARG_MAX` it returns `131072`.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I'm familiar with using `xargs` with `grep` but I'm not exactly sure when one must use it with other commands such as `rm`. Because, for example, obviously you wouldn't use it with `ls`.